# Remove ExtJs 4 default class

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, extjs4

I'm trying to remove a default class from an element, however the class does not have a single selector.  The class is assigned like this:

```
.x3-scope .x-form-grow-sizer {
    font:normal 12px tahoma, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

I've tried this:

```
Ext.get("test1234567").removeClass(".x3-scope .x-form-grow-sizer");
```

But it doesn't work.  Should it?

Comment: why dont you overwrite your class by add your class and type !important after the css propety like height:20px!important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question because I realised the obvious answer moments after posting!

Simply removing the second selector means that the css rule no longer applies.

```
Ext.get("test1234567").removeClass("x-form-grow-sizer");
```

Answer (score 1):

The method accepts a string or an array as parameter, so this would work

```
el.removeClass(["x3-scope","x-form-grow-sizer"]);
```

After looking at the Ext source, your original approach would have worked as well if you had the class names specified without the `.`

```
el.removeClass("x3-scope x-form-grow-sizer");
```

(The method will tokenize/split a string argument into an array internally).

Comment: Upvoting - confirmed, but for the sake of completeness, the correct name of the function is "removeCls".